# How to suppress logs of interaction with solr8.8.1/zookeeper (not written explicitly by my application)

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud, wildfly-9

I have an web application, that uses an solr 8.8.1 cluster, and I use wildfly-9.0.2.Final to run it. When the app interacts with solr/zookeeper a log that I doesn't control is written in wildfly log file. Is written as a ERROR log with an embebed INFO log inside it. My app don't have dependents .jar files in it, it uses modules provided in wildfly.

I have tried for example add this file to my app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><jboss-deployment-structure>
<deployment>
    <exclude-subsystems>
        <subsystem name="logging" />
    </exclude-subsystems>
</deployment>
```

Anyone clue how to supress this interaction logs?

Thanks.

`CloudSolrClient client = null; public DidYouMeanSolrClient() { this.client = new CloudSolrClient.Builder(Arrays.asList("srv-solr-01:2181,srv-solr-02:2181,srv-solr-03:2181"), java.util.Optional.empty()).build(); this.client.setDefaultCollection("default_collection_name"); }`

**2021-05-10 12:59:58,301 ERROR [stderr] (default task-3) 24291 [default task-3] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Initiating client connection, connectString=...**

2021-05-10 12:59:58,303 ERROR [stderr] (default task-3) 24293 [default task-3] INFO
org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocket - jute.maxbuffer value is 1048575 Bytes

2021-05-10 12:59:58,304 ERROR [stderr] (default task-3) 24294 [default task-3] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - zookeeper.request.timeout value is 0. feature enabled=false

2021-05-10 12:59:58,304 ERROR [stderr] (default task-3) 24294 [default task-3] INFO org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ConnectionManager - Waiting for client to connect to ZooKeeper

2021-05-10 12:59:58,307 ERROR [stderr] (default task-3-SendThread(server)) 24297 [default task-3-SendThread(server)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Opening socket connection to server ...

2021-05-10 12:59:58,312 ERROR [stderr] (default task-3-SendThread(server)) 24302 [default task-3-SendThread(server)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Socket connection established, initiating session, client: ..., server: ...

2021-05-10 12:59:58,316 ERROR [stderr] (default task-3-SendThread(server)) 24306 [default task-3-SendThread(server)] INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Session establishment complete on server ..., session id = 0x2000000cecd003b, negotiated timeout = 40000

2021-05-10 12:59:58,316 ERROR [stderr] (zkConnectionManagerCallback-10-thread-1) 24306 [zkConnectionManagerCallback-10-thread-1] INFO org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ConnectionManager - zkClient has connected

2021-05-10 12:59:58,317 ERROR [stderr] (default task-3) 24307 [default task-3] INFO org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ConnectionManager - Client is connected to ZooKeeper

2021-05-10 12:59:58,323 ERROR [stderr] (default task-3) 24313 [default task-3] INFO org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ZkStateReader - Updated live nodes from ZooKeeper... (0) -> (3)

2021-05-10 12:59:58,327 ERROR [stderr] (default task-3) 24317 [default task-3] INFO org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.ZkClientClusterStateProvider - Cluster at srv-solr-01:2181,srv-solr-02:2181,srv-solr-03:2181 ready

Comment: It looks like you've got some kind of logging configuration in your deployment. Do you have a log4j.xml or log4j.properties in your deployment?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. No, I have nothing related to log4j in my project :(

Comment: Given the format it looks like something is writing to `System.err` and formatted like a log formatter.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I will try to find the problem in the next days. If I find the solution I will post it in here.